# Compute the first four terms of the Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

"By multiplying the appropriate Taylor series about $c=0$, compute the first four terms of the Taylor series about $c=0$ for $f(x)=e^{-x}\cos x$."

Seems straightforward enough but when I break up $e^{-x}$ and $\cos(x)$ then multiply their terms together I am getting something different than an online Taylor Series calculator is coming up with. Here's what I'm getting for the terms of the two functions and then their product:

$$e^{-x} \longrightarrow  1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6}\\
 \cos(x) \longrightarrow  1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$$

Now, I only used the first two terms of $\cos(x)$ when I multiplied and I came up with:

$$1 - x +\frac{x^3}{2} \underbrace{- \frac{x^4}{4}}$$ The underbrace denotes difference between my answer and the online calculator.

The online calculator is getting the following:

$$1 - x +\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{6}$$

If I'm making a basic multiplication mistake I have missed it several times. Can anyone help point to my mistake?  Many thanks..

Comment: You forgot to multiply the $-\frac{x^3}{6}$ from $e^{-x}$ with the $1$ from $\cos x$, and you have two products $1\cdot \frac{x^4}{24}$, one from each, that you also forgot.

Comment: My mistake, I only utilized the first three terms of e^-x. So I multiplied the following:

(1 - x + (x^2)/2 ) * (1 - (x^2)/2) and got (1 - x + (x^3)/2* - (x^4)/4*)

I should have mentioned that in the initial post.

Comment: For a control, use $f(x)=\Re e^{(-1+i)x}=\Re(1+(-1+i)x+(-1+i)^2\frac{x^2}2+(-1+i)^3\frac{x^3}6+(-1+i)^4\frac{x^4}{24}...)$.

Comment: The sum of the first four terms is $1+(-1)x+(0)x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3$, it is OK to leave out the $x^4$ in the calculation.